# php string replace wild card

Tags: php, str-replace

I have something like this and I want to trim all contents except this part as its user generated data we don't have complete control but the pattern is completely controlled so users data should be like this only and I want only this part

This is the part I want:

```
  <b id="timer"></b>
```

The total user submitted string should look like this:

```
  <b id="timer" style="font-family:"Mono";color:"#fgt875";"></b>
```

I want to use str_replace or preg replace to achieve this.
Is it possible?

Comment: `fgt875` is not color hex.

Comment: Consider something like HTML Purifier for this. You can give it specific tags, classes, and attributes to permit. http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code -

```
<?php

    $str = '<b id="timer" style="font-family:"Mono";color:"#fgt875";"></b>';

    echo preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(?:[^>]*(\sid=['\"][^'\"]*['\"]))?[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $str);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working.

Reference Link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
<?php
    $dm = '<p>Dhaval</p>';
    echo preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(?:[^>]*(\sid=['\"][^'\"]*['\"]))?[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $dm);
?>
```